# Is it possible to create unique constraint accross multiple properties over multiple nodes in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, constraints, graph-databases

Let's say I have two labels A, B in Neo4j. is it possible to create something like the following ?

create constraint  where A.property1 and B.property2 is unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, constraints are on one label only.

If you decide to create some new label, :A_B for example, then you can assert that its property1, property2 properties act as a [node key constraint](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/constraints/#administration-constraints-node-key), though this is an enterprise feature only.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no way to create a uniqueness constraint that spans multiple nodes, here is a Cypher query that shows one way you can perform a uniqueness test spanning 2 nodes before creating one of the nodes (if appropriate):

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (a:A), (b:B)
WHERE a.property1 = $p1 AND b.property1 = $p2
FOREACH(x IN CASE WHEN a IS NULL THEN [1] END |
  MERGE (a:A {property1: $p1}))
```

The query assumes `p1` and `p2` are passed in as [parameters](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/). If either `a.property1 = $p1` OR `b.property1 = $p2` are false, then `a` will be null after the `WHERE` clause. Thus, the `FOREACH` clause will only create (if necessary, via a `MERGE` clause) one of those nodes if the multi-node uniqueness test fails. `MERGE` is used to avoid creating that node if it already exists.